# Magento 2: Rest API Contact Us Form

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.4, contact-us

Need to Create Rest API for Contact Us form. Submit contact us form via rest API and send an email.

**API Name:** Contact Us API

**Method:** POST

**API URL:**  {baseurl}/rest/V1/contactus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created custom contact us API. This is a helpful for submit contact us form via rest API and send an email.

**API Name:** Contact Us API

**Description:**
    Submit a contact us form to send an email.

**API URL:** http://127.0.0.1/magento2/rest/V1/contactus?contactForm[name]=Kirti&contactForm[email]=kirtinariya80@gmail.com&contactForm[telephone]=1234567890&contactForm[comment]=Testcomment

**Params:**

```
contactForm[name]                  Kirti
contactForm[email]                 kirtinariya80@gmail.com
contactForm[telephone]             1234567890
contactForm[comment]               Testcomment
```

**Method:** POST

**Response:**

```
{    
    "message": "Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We'll respond to you very soon."
}
```

Follow below file path to create Contact Us custom module For Contact Us API.

> **File path:** magento2/app/code/Vendor/ContactusApi/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ContactusApi',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **File path:** magento2/app/code/Vendor/ContactusApi/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ContactusApi" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> **File path:** magento2/app/code/Vendor/ContactusApi/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/contactus" method="POST">
        <service class="Vendor\ContactusApi\Api\ContactusManagementInterface" method="submitForm"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>   
</routes>
```

> **File path:** magento2/app/code/Vendor/ContactusApi/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\ContactusApi\Api\ContactusManagementInterface" type="Vendor\ContactusApi\Model\ContactusManagement"/>
</config>
```

> **File path:**
>   magento2/app/code/Vendor/ContactusApi/Api/ContactusManagementInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ContactusApi\Api;

/**
 * Interface ContactusManagementInterface
 *
 * @package Vendor\ContactusApi\Api
 */
interface ContactusManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * Contact us form.
     *
     * @param mixed $contactForm
     *
     * @return \Vendor\ContactusApi\Api\Data\ContactusInterface
     */
    public function submitForm($contactForm);
}
```

> **File path:**
>   magento2/app/code/Vendor/ContactusApi/Api/Data/ContactusInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ContactusApi\Api\Data;

/**
 * ContactusInterface interface
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
interface ContactusInterface
{
    /**
    * @return \Vendor\ContactusApi\Api\Data\ContactusInterface[]
     */
    public function getMessage();

    /**
     * @param string $message
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMessage($message);
}
```

> **File path:**
>   magento2/app/code/Vendor/ContactusApi/Model/ContactusManagement.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ContactusApi\Model;

use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Vendor\ContactusApi\Api\ContactusManagementInterface;

/**
 * Class ContactusManagement
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class ContactusManagement implements ContactusManagementInterface
{ 
    private $mail;

    protected $dataObjectFactory;

    public function __construct(
        MailInterface $mail,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory
    ) {
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
    }

    /**
    * @inheritDoc
    */
    public function submitForm($contactForm) {
        $result = $this->dataObjectFactory->create();

        if (empty($contactForm['name'])) {
            $result->setData('message', 'Enter the Name and try again.');
            return $result;
        }
        if (empty($contactForm['email'])) {
            $result->setData('message', 'Enter the Email and try again.');
            return $result;
        }
        if (false === \strpos($contactForm['email'], '@') || false === \strpos($contactForm['email'], '.com')) {
            $result->setData('message', 'The email address is invalid. Verify the email address and try again.');
            return $result;
        }
        if (empty($contactForm['comment'])) {
            $result->setData('message', 'Enter the Comment and try again.');
            return $result;
        }

        try {
            $this->sendEmail($contactForm);
            $result->setData('message', 'Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $result->setData('message', $e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result->setData('message', 'An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.');
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $post Post data from contact form
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendEmail($post)
    {
        $this->mail->send(
            $post['email'],
            ['data' => new DataObject($post)]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to receive an email after submitting data using API, the response is getting correct in Postman. What is missing? need to mention an email template or specific email?

Comment: Are you checking in local ?

Comment: No, I am checking on the server.
http://qa-shop.workforceinstitute.io/rest/V1/contactus?contactForm[firstname]=Wajahat&contactForm[lastname]=Bashir&contactForm[email]=wajahat.bashir@edtechventures.io&contactForm[phone]=0562179194&contactForm[interested]=IT&contactForm[designation]=Magento Dev&contactForm[comment]=This is testing message